# Вывод данных из БД для текущий записи в WP

Tags: wordpress, база-данных

Как правильно составить функцию для вывода карты Google с заданными координатами из БД?

Вот пример записи из таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `post_id`, `longitude` и `latitude`.

И полученные данные в скрипт:

```
<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
<div id="map"></div>
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 0000000, lng: 000000},
zoom: 8
});
}
</script>
```

То есть, пройтись по таблице и в случае совпадения ID текущего материала с `post_id` из таблицы подставить `longitude` и `latitude` в скрипт, который выведет данные на странице.

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

$record = $wpdb->get_row(
$wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * from wp_marker where post_id = %d', $current_post_id )
);

if ( $record ) {
    ?>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
        <div id="map"></div>
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: <?php echo esc_html( $record->latitude ); ?>,
                    lng: <?php echo esc_html( $record->longitude ); ?>
                },
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

`get_the_ID()` работает только внутри основного цикла WordPress. Если у вас уже получено значение текущего поста, то его надо использовать в `prepare()` вместо `$current_post_id`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, то, что нужно. А как проверить наличие в таблице нужно id совпадающего с текущим id записи? Чтоб убрать скрипт, если данные на карте отсутствуют? Просто обернуть скрипт в `if($current_post_id = esc_html($record->post_id);) {...}`?

Comment: Дополнил ответ: `if ($record)`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!